# Splice() method not works

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, splice

I have some problem with splice() method in my React.js app.

So, **[this is an example app](http://codepen.io/azat-io/pen/Vaxyjv)**. Deletion not works now. What's wrong here? Part of code:

```js
class CardList extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    students: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
  };
  // ADD DELETE FUNCTION
  deletePerson(person) {
    this.props.students.splice(this.props.students.indexOf(person), 1)
    this.setState()
  }
  render() {
    let that = this
    return <div id='list'>
      {this.props.students.map((person) => {
        return <Card
          onClick={that.deletePerson.bind(null, person)}
          name={person.name}>
        </Card>
      })}
    </div>
  }
}

class Card extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div className='card'>
       <p>{this.props.name}</p>
      {/* ADD DELETE BUTTON */}
      <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>Delete</button>
    </div>
  }
}
```

http://codepen.io/azat-io/pen/Vaxyjv

Comment: You should never try to modify the props. Use the state instead: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html (using `setState`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that when you call

```
onClick={that.deletePerson.bind(null, person)}
```

You bind `this` value to `null`. So inside of your `deletePerson` function `this` is `null` instead of actual component. You should change it to

```
onClick={that.deletePerson.bind(this, person)}
```

And everything would work as expected =)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the bind value to `this` will definitely cause the call to `this.setState()` to work, thus triggering the re-render, however I strongly recommend against the approach you've taken.

Props are supposed to be immutable. Instead use internal state and replace with new values rather than mutate them. To do this, set the state of your component in the constructor by doing something like:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        students: ...this.props.students
    }
}
```

And now when you need to delete a person:

```
deletePerson(person) {
    // notice the use of slice vs splice
    var newStudents = this.props.students.slice(this.props.students.indexOf(person), 1)
    this.setState({ students: newStudents })
}
```

And finally use `this.state.students` in your render method instead.

The reasoning behind this is that `props` are passed directly from the parent container component so modifying them wouldn't really make sense. To make more sense of my own code, I tend to pass in the prop named `initialStudents` and set my state to `students: ...initialStudents` to ensure I make the distinction between my prop variable and my state variable.